# Animated background not staying fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Hey guys i am working on a new background for my website. I am trying to animate it a little more. I am currently working here: http://wow-x.com/back/

As you can see, when you scroll down the page the div called "background" does not stay "fixed" ... I can't seem to be able to make it stay fixed.

My CSS looks like this:

```
body {
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(http://wow-x.com/board/images/blackevo4-pure/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#background {
    background: url(http://wow-x.com/board/images/blackevo4-pure/back1.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    opacity:0.1;
    z-index:-1;
}

#midground {
    background: url(http://wow-x.com/board/images/blackevo4-pure/midground.png) repeat 20% 20%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:-2;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#foreground {
    background: url(http://wow-x.com/board/images/blackevo4-pure/foreground.png) repeat 90% 110%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:-3;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to keep the `#background` div fixed, change it's position from `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to keep the `#background` div fixed, change it's position from `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;`

Setting the `position` attribute to absolute means the element will be positioned relative to it's first positioned ancestor. In your case, this is the body itself and so the image scrolls along with the page.

Setting the `position` attribute to fixed means the element will be positioned relative to the window. So it's position will be independent of the scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix use..

```
position:fixed
```

to your #background